# Using GridView inside View Pager Fragment

Tags: android, gridview

How can i refresh the `GridView` inside a fragment of a view pager?

1. I have already tried using `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` , but that's not working .
2. I want to delete the elements from `gridView` and refresh the grid view.
3. I am removing the elements from the `arrayList` and `gridvIew.getCount()` shows decreased         values but it shows the deleted values in grid view , How can I update/refresh the `gridView` ?

The layout of fragement is dynamically created so no fragemt tag to findfragement by id.

Comment: delete the  data that you use to populate gridview call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` update/refresh listview

Comment: already tried but thats not working , anything else that i could do

Comment: solved it , i was calling pagerAdater.notifyDataSetChanged(), removed it and starts working , but it comes back when i scroll pages , How can i remove that

Comment: hey i am trying to use GridView inside ViewPager but fail to understand how do i use it. If you can help me with this as you have already done something similar to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok while scrolling back to the fragment with grid view repopulate the grid inside viewpager on PageChangeListener